# Connect to authenticated REST service c# to get back JSON data

Tags: c#, python, http, rest, bitbucket

I am trying to call a REST Api to get back some JSON data and I can't make it connect. I think it needs a cached cookie or something to work. Any ideas or people that have used the REST Bitbucket.org api? Here is api address I am using https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/user/repositories/. It works if you used directly in the web browswer.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RESTApiPath"]) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"]);

        //request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        // Get response
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            // Console application output
            string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonData))
                ParseNames(jsonData);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what goes over the wire when it works (browser) and when it doesn't work (your code)... once you know the differences you can change your code accordingly...